# How to use enzyme ShallowWrapper to find a React Component stored as a prop in another React Component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, semantic-ui-react

I have a jest/enzyme test which creates a ShallowWrapper around a component, finds a specified semantic-ui-react Button (by id), simulates a click on the button, and then looks to see if the click toggled certain content.

Sample JSX:

```
<Popup
  trigger={<Button onClick={this.toggleShowThing} id="special-btn">a button</Button>}
  content="Popup Words"
/>
{this.state.showThing &&
  <div className="special-thing">The Thing's Words</div>
}
```

Sample Test:

```
it('shows the thing when the button is clicked', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  wrapper.find('#special-btn').simulate('click', { preventDefault() {} });
  expect(wrapper.find('.special-thing').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

This test worked when I just had the Button. When I added the Popup and the Button was placed into the trigger prop then I received an error because #special-btn could not be found.

> Error: Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

An enzyme snapshot of the component shows that the Popup looks like this:

```
<Popup 
  content="Popup Words"
  on="hover"
  position="top left"
  trigger={
    <Button
      id="special-btn"
      onClick={[Function]}
    >
      a button
    </Button>
  }
/>
```

I need my test to work again. How do I gain access to the #special-btn again in the test so that I can call .simulate('click') on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Popup is some third-party component that has already been tested, I would approach testing the following way:

(1) Find the Popup and check if the `trigger` prop's Button's `onClick` prop is `componentWrapper.instance().toggleShowThing`

(2) As a separate thing, set `this.state.showThing` to false and verify no div with className special-thing is rendered; set `this.state.showThing` to true and verify it is rendered.

(*) `this.toggleShowThing` should also be tested on its own.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me, although there is no documentation for it:

```js
import {shallow, ShallowWrapper} from "enzyme";

it('shows the thing when the button is clicked', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  const button = new ShallowWrapper(
    wrapper.find('Popup').prop('trigger'), wrapper
  );
  button.simulate('click', { preventDefault() {} });
  expect(wrapper.find('.special-thing').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

In other words:

1. Find the `Popup` component.
2. Get the component rendered in its `trigger` prop. Note that this is not yet a shallow wrapper, so no fancy APIs yet.
3. Manually create the wrapper using `ShallowWrapper` (it's important to pass the second argument).
4. Now you can access all the enzyme APIs to interact with the button.

Note, it seems that you can avoid using the constructor and use [wrap()](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/440c0627d325d9dd44319608a9b7dd2d3bb2bde7/packages/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L1665) utility method instead (also not documented):

```js
  const button = wrapper.wrap(wrapper.find('Popup').prop('trigger'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot do it. You need to rewrite your test. Your button is now wrapped by a `Popup` component thus you don't have access to it. But you can move your selector to the `Popup` and test if clicking the popup triggers required change. There's no other way around.

```
// JSX
<Popup
  trigger={<Button onClick={this.toggleShowThing} id="special-btn">a button</Button>}
  content="Popup Words"
  id="popup"
/>
{this.state.showThing &&
  <div className="special-thing">The Thing's Words</div>
}

// test
it('shows the thing when the button is clicked', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  wrapper.find('#popup').simulate('click', { preventDefault() {} });
  expect(wrapper.find('.special-thing').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: I tested your recommendation, unfortunately it does not work. The ShallowWrapper is able to find the Popup, but the simulated click event may not be propagating to the actual Button and so doesn't call this.toggleShowThing(). I'm guessing this is from shallow rendering?

Comment: @FrostyFox perhaps you should try to mount the component instead of shallow rendering. shallow rendering doesn't propagate the events down the component.